# Yocto: Unable to include pSplash

Tags: raspberry-pi, yocto

Background:

I'm compiling an Image using core-image-minimal.
Poky is on branch dunfell and compiling with meta-raspberrypi.

I've removed the references to psplash within meta-raspberrypi.

When adding:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append += " psplash"
IMAGE_FEATURES += " splash"
SPLASH = " psplash-default"
```

to my local.conf.
However, the image is not populated with /usr/bin/psplash, resulting in the error:

```
psplash-start.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/bin/psplash: No such file or directory
```

There is a line in psplash_git.bb that looks suspicious to me, but removing it results in a scriplet error on compile:

```
rm -f ${D}${bindir}/psplash
```

Interesting when checking the ./tmp directory, I can see that the binary has actually compiled, it is just not copied to the sysroot.

Has anyone had experience with this? Am I doing something very wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " psplash"`